# How foursquare check-in work

Tags: geolocation, foursquare

I building a similar check-in system like foursquare. I have a tables with list of locations with lat,lng. User on mobile will send a request to find location near their position with radius about 5km. How to achieve that? Are there any best practice model?

Comment: its called trigonometry. in fact in this case even simpler: convert to coordinate system and use dist = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)

Comment: So I need to fetch all locations in table and check distance?

Comment: dist = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)

Comment: How to convert lat, lng to coordinate system?

Comment: @MitchWheat if he didn't why would he be here?

Answer (score 0):

This is ideally done using a geospatial indexing system.

To make it easier on yourself, use a database with one of these built-in. MongoDB is a common example.

It allows you do perform this type of query in a similar way to other types of database queries without requiring a separate system to do the indexing (such as solr, or postgis).

See the documentation for more information:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing